# Ошибка при удалениеи элементов в цикле for ... in

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, циклы

Надо создать функцию, где на входе будет список предложений, а на выходе из предложений удаляются все слова, содержащие цифры, специальные знаки, т.е. не буквы.

Например:

```
input: ['1 thousand devils', 'My name is 9Pasha', 'Room #125 costs $100']
output: ['thousand devils', 'My name is', 'Room costs']
```

Написал следующий код:

```
def process(sentences):
    result = []
    a = 0
    for item in sentences:
        item = item.split(' ') #Каждое предложение разбивается на отдельный список
        for word in item:
            a += 1
            print(a) #Добавил счетчик, чтобы легче понять на каком слове происходит ошибка
            for letter in word:
                if str.isalpha(letter) == False:
                    item.remove(word) #В одной из итераций здесь происходит ошибка
        item = ' '.join(item) #Предложения соединяются обратно в строку
        result.append(item)
    return result

A = ['1 thousand devils', 'My name is 9Pasha', 'Room #125 costs $100']
B = process(A)
print(B)
```

По моим расчетам, из предложения (`item`) должно удалиться слово (`word`), в котором очередная итерация нашла недопустимый символ, но выводится ошибка:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    B = process(A)
  File "test.py", line 11, in process
    item.remove(word)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

PS Буду рад и другим способ решения задачи, но мне крайне интересно понять саму суть ошибки, откуда вообще Python взял переменную `x`.

Python 3.7.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Альтернативное решение с использованием `list comprehension`:

```
res = [" ".join(word for word in sent.split() if word.isalpha())
       for sent in sentences]
```

результат:

```
In [45]: res
Out[45]: ['thousand devils', 'My name is', 'Room costs']
```

---

PS метод [str.isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) - позволяет проверять целую строку, соотвественно нет необходимости проверять каждую букву в слове.

Comment: Гениально, спасибо. Только сейчас понял, что можно было проверять целиком слова (хотя я вроде и до этого знал). Кстати, я попробовал отредактировать свой код (без применения `list comprehension`) с учетом этого и ошибка пропала. Может быть интерпретатор упирается именно в большое количество вложенных циклов (хотя этого быть не должно) ...

Comment: @TigranRostomyan, добавил [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1098111/211923), объясняющий причину возникновения ошибки)

Answer (score 4):

Легче всего понять причину ошибки добавив отладочную информацию:

я добавил строку `print(f"removing word: [{word}] from [{item}]")` в ваш код:

```
def process(sentences):
    result = []
    a = 0
    for item in sentences:
        item = item.split(' ') #Каждое предложение разбивается на отдельный список
        for word in item:
            a += 1
            print(a) #Добавил счетчик, чтобы легче понять на каком слове происходит ошибка
            for letter in word:
                if str.isalpha(letter) == False:
                    print(f"removing word: [{word}] from [{item}]")
                    item.remove(word) #В одной из итераций здесь происходит ошибка
        item = ' '.join(item) #Предложения соединяются обратно в строку
        result.append(item)
    return result
```

---

вывод:

```
In [58]: process(sentences)
1
removing word: [1] from [['1', 'thousand', 'devils']]
2
3
4
5
6
removing word: [9Pasha] from [['My', 'name', 'is', '9Pasha']]
7
8
removing word: [#125] from [['Room', '#125', 'costs', '$100']]
removing word: [#125] from [['Room', 'costs', '$100']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-c110f32279b9> in <module>
----> 1 process(sentences)

<ipython-input-57-23b8232cb157> in process(sentences)
     10                 if str.isalpha(letter) == False:
     11                     print(f"removing word: [{word}] from [{item}]")
---> 12                     item.remove(word) #В одной из итераций здесь происходит ошибка
     13         item = ' '.join(item) #Предложения соединяются обратно в строку
     14         result.append(item)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Мне кажется следующие строки наглядно объясняют причину возникновения ошибки:

```
removing word: [#125] from [['Room', '#125', 'costs', '$100']]
removing word: [#125] from [['Room', 'costs', '$100']]
```

Comment: Благодаря вашему ответу понял причину ошибки: получается, что цикл `for letter in word` при проверке слова где более одного недопустимого символа, при первой же итерации удаляет слово и списка, но при этом проходит по остальным символам слова, каждый раз пытаясь снова удалить уже удаленное слово. Как то так :)

Comment: @TigranRostomyan, да, вы все правильно поняли)